# Setting default value in entity class is not working incase of OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, opencsv

I have a csv file from where i will read the data and map it to corresponding java object using opencsv.
I have my entity class like below

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="student_info")
public class Student {
  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
  private String name;

  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
  private boolean isBusFacilityAvailed;

  @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
  private Integer busFee = 0;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "markSheet", fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
  private List<MarkSheet> marks;
}
```

Here i may not get busFee information if isBusFacilityAvailed is false. In Database busFee column should not be saved as null instead it should be saved as 0 if the information is not present.

For that purpose i have given default value as 0 in the above class for busFee field and that works fine when i don't have OneToMany mapping in my entity class.

But when i add OneToMany mapping in the entity class it is not working, the value for busFee is getting saved as null in DB.

Is there any other way how i could resolve this issue.

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: We are using Azure SQL server

Comment: Can't you set a default value for the column in the DB then?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here your class is doing more than one thing. It's both a DTO to read from a CSV file and an Entity object to deal with the database.

If you separate your concerns here and create a class whose only purpose is to read from a CSV file and keep the entity as is then you can transform the DTO to an entity which will make it easier for you to understand where the problem is or lack of it thereby.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `@Column` annotation with `columnDefinition`  to **busFee** filed

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
private Integer busFee = 0;
```

Let us know if this works